# New User profile page?

Tags: feature-request

Some of the other Stacks have a newer looking Profile page, with changes and new features. Is EE slated for this or does it need to be requested? Will/Can it be implemented here?

[image]

From [Profile Page Makeover, Part 3: the Prototype returns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) it seems this new status page was supposed to be complete in Jan, and go live by Feb site wide.

> In the next few weeks we will preview further profile changes here on MSE - mostly to the activity page and following feedback and rework on those, the new profile page will go live to the rest of the network (6-8 weeks, give or take).

Comment: SE crew is gradually updating stacks one-by-one with new user profile designs.  For instance Programmers.SE got the new user profile design a few weeks ago.